# Quick way to modify MS SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I need to edit Microsoft SQL stored procedures frequently and i found the traditional way (Open MSSMS -> expand the databases tree, expand the stored procedures tree and define filter by the name of the SP) very long. i am looking for a way (command line) like "sp_helptext " but a way that will actually open for me the stored procedure for edit.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `EXEC sp_HelpText 'Procedure Name'` .Copy the result and paste it in ssms and use `Alter Procedure` instead of `create` to modify the sp .But instead of doing these the best option is to use `filter` settings in `Stored Procedure folder`.

Comment: script it and save into file , keep it on the desktop :o

Comment: Why are you editing stored procedures directly? You should be working with SQL scripts in source control, so you open the script, edit it, then execute it to modify the procedure. There are many ways to do this depending on your preferred tools and source control system, but directly editing database objects is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Redgate SQL Prompt. With this you can right click the Stored Proc's name and click "ALTER"

[RED GATE SQL PROMPT](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/)

Comment: I found that sometimes RED GATE shows me the content from its cache and its not the most updated version... Maybe because i am using an old version.

Comment: There is a refresh suggestions which I tend to click every now and then

Comment: If you try the Experimental Features (you'll find them in the SQL Prompt menu), you can enable the Automatic Refresh Suggestions option.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct command like

```
MODIFY dbname.schemaname.spname
```

You have 3 options that use TSQL, apart from the traditional GUI way using SSMS

```
EXEC sp_helptext dbname.schemaname.spname';

SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(dbname.schemaname.spname'));

SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = (OBJECT_ID(dbname.schemaname.spname'));
```

Unfortunately, all these options will result in loss of formatting.

You are trying to mix two technologies here.

1. SQL and SQLSyntax
2. The SQL Management Tool

It is probably not possible to use TSQL to manipulate the Management Studio, which is what you appear to want. I am afraid cut and paste is your only option.

Raj

Answer (score 3):

There is a way: I develop SSMSBoost - add-in for SSMS. It allows to open object scripts directly from SQL Editor.

1. In SQL Editor Place cursor on stored procedure name
2. Hit F2 and procedure will be scripted in new window.

Hitting Ctrl-F2 would locate object in object explorer tree, so you can use further SSMS commands right-clicking it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i prefer an open source utilities. do you know one?

Comment: There are some open source add-ins, but they do not do what is asked here in this question. My add-in is not open source but can be used currently for free

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that you can use to run the sp_helptext procedure which will give you back a table of rows that you can write to a file that will create the stored procedure.  You can then pass the filename into the SSMS command line to open that file directly when sql server manager opens.

> ex) Ssms tempFile.sql

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection ("Connection String Here"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_helptext @procName";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("procName", "Name Of Stored Proc Here");

        con.Open(); 

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                /* 
                You will get the CREATE PROC text here
                Do what you need to with it. For example, write
                to a .sql file
                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever use SSMS (or an SSMS add-in) to script stored procs for change. The stored procs should always be opened directly from your source control instead. If you don't have these objects in source control, then  you need to do so. SPs are code, they need to be treated just like other code. It is irresponsible to edit sps scripted from outside the source control system.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_NAME = 'YourStoredProcedureName'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to ignore the advice here about source control, a quick-ish way would be to create a .sql file on your desktop that you can launch easily, containing the following.

```
SELECT o.name, m.definition AS [Copy This Definition], o.type_desc, o.create_date, o.modify_date 
FROM sys.sql_modules m INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.name='the_SP_in_question' -- <<<<<< SP/Func to search for
```

Edit the SP name as required before F5-ing, then copy the definition in the results into a new query. And change the `CREATE` to `ALTER` of course.

It's a shame that MS haven't provided a standard command yet for doing this, it would have its uses.